# JSF/Hibernate Como fazer para gravar null em um campo do banco?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, hibernate, jpa

Tenho uma aplicação usando Primefaces/JPA-Hibernate/TomCat8, e preciso que quando um campo na tela estiver vazio, ele grave `null` no banco (Postgres). Preciso disso pois tenho alguns campos no banco de dados que possuem UniqueKey, e mesmo quando o campo esta vazio na tela, e grava uma string vazia no banco -> `''`

Já estou usando o parâmetro: `javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL` e parece não surtir efeito. Ja usei Converter para deixar nulo a String vazia, e também na funciona, pois quando o valor chega até minha entidade a string esta vazia novamente e não nula. Falta alguma lib ou não como fazer isso que eu quero mesmo?

Comment: `default null` nas colunas? *Entity listener*? `PrePersist` e/ou `PreUpdate` na(s) entidades que você precisa?

Comment: fiz um teste utilizando o wildfly e o parametro javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL é obedecido! Seria um problema do tomcat8 entao?

Comment: Ao subir o tomcat, inclua esse trecho na `JVM_OPTION`: `-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false`. Veja se funciona, isto deveria afetar apenas número, mas lembro de ter problemas com isso em uma versão dele.

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar que ja estava usando essa opcao de COERCE_TO_ZERO=false e tambem nao surtiu efeito.

Answer (score 1):

Coloca o valor default  nulo no campo da sua entidade!

```
private String valor = null;
```

Comment: `Null` já é o valor default de qualquer objeto.